# Perl - add Devel::Cover to the ExtUtils::MakeMaker in make test

Tags: perl

I want to do this:

```
make test
```

and runs as a

```
HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover make test
```

if possible runs the cover in the end.

I try to do this but does not work.

```
test  => { HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES => '-MDevel::Cover' },
```

but read the manual with more attention I see it is not possible.

BTW can I add something like

```
make cover
```

who can do this to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Dist::Zilla, there is a plugin which allows you to issue a [dzil cover](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aApp%3a%3aCommand%3a%3acover) at shell.